# Xamarin Android Checkbox Clickable doesn't work

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm currently working on a project using Mvvm.cross framework with Xamarin in Visual studio. Here is my issue.

I have 2 custom checkboxes:

**checkbox_approve:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:state_checked="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/approved" />

  <item android:state_checked="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/circle_unchecked" />

</selector>
```

**checkbox_reject:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:state_checked="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/rejected" />

  <item android:state_checked="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/circle_unchecked" />

</selector>
```

**Here is code in `ReportResponseView.axml` file:**

```
                  <dc.AlphaRelativeLayout 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    local:MvxBind="Click ApprovedCommand"> *//this is binding to ViewModel for different purposes*
                        <CheckBox 
                        android:id="@+id/approvedCheckBox"
                        android:button="@drawable/checkbox_approve"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        local:MvxBind="Checked IsApproved" /> *//this is binding to ViewModel for different purposes*
                    </dc.AlphaRelativeLayout>
                    <dc.AlphaRelativeLayout 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    local:MvxBind="Click RejectedCommand">
                        <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/rejectedCheckBox"
                        android:button="@drawable/checkbox_reject"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        local:MvxBind="Checked IsRejected" />
                    </dc.AlphaRelativeLayout>
```

**I want is: if user clicks into 1 checkbox, the second checkbox will be unclickable. Here is the code in `ReportResponseView.cs:`**

```
 protected override void InitView(View view)
        {
            approveCheckBox = (CheckBox)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.approvedCheckBox);
            rejectCheckBox = (CheckBox)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.rejectedCheckBox);

            approveCheckBox.CheckedChange += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (approveCheckBox.Checked)
                {
                    rejectCheckBox.Clickable = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    rejectCheckBox.Clickable = true;
                }
            };

            rejectCheckBox.CheckedChange += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (rejectCheckBox.Checked)
                {
                    approveCheckBox.Clickable = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    approveCheckBox.Clickable = true;
                }
            };
        }
```

`approveCheckBox.Clickable` doesn't work somehow for both checkbox. When I click into 1 checkbox, the 2nd one is still clickable. 
I wonder if I'm doing a wrong way?

Comment: Check for enable and disable property

Comment: Do you want radio button functionality in checkbox?

Comment: @ramyabr I did and It didnt work

Comment: Did you set a break point, to check if the methods are being called?

Comment: yeah, I did, the value of rejectCheckBox.Clickable is changed into true or false exactly. But rejectCheckbox can be checked when it its clickable = false @BrunoCaceiro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The issue** is I have `click event` on 2 `AlphaRelativeLayout` which cover 2 checkboxs always allow user to click onto `AlphaRelativeLayout`, then makes 2 checkboxs obviously clickable

**Here is the solution**: I adjusted 2 methods `ApprovedCommand` and `RejectedCommand` a bit in ViewModel then I just need to move Click Event from `AlphaRelativeLayout` to `Checkbox` properties

```
               <dc.AlphaRelativeLayout 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <CheckBox 
                    android:id="@+id/approvedCheckBox"
                    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_approve"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    local:MvxBind="Click ApprovedCommand" />
                </dc.AlphaRelativeLayout>
                <dc.AlphaRelativeLayout 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/rejectedCheckBox"
                    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_reject"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    local:MvxBind="Click RejectedCommand" />
                </dc.AlphaRelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use enabled false property to prevent clickable

```
       protected override void InitView(View view)
        {
           approveCheckBox = 
          (CheckBox)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.approvedCheckBox);
            rejectCheckBox = 
            (CheckBox)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.rejectedCheckBox);

            approveCheckBox.CheckedChange += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (approveCheckBox.Checked)
                {
                    rejectCheckBox.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    rejectCheckBox.Enabled = true;
                }
            };

            rejectCheckBox.CheckedChange += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (rejectCheckBox.Checked)
                {
                    approveCheckBox.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    approveCheckBox.Enabled = true;
                }
            };
        }
```

Comment: @vyclarks Should you not be enabling/disabling your `AlphaRelativeLayout` as well as that also has a click event on it which I assume is also setting the `IsApproved` and `IsRejected` properties in your view model.

Comment: thank you @c.lamont.dev, it's exactly the point that causes the issue. I've just adjusted the code and it finally works fine. I will update the right code in my answer.